# OpenVPN can not access shared drives on network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, windows-server-2008-r2

I am having trouble accessing our shared network drives when I am connected through the VPN.
When I am physically in the office and connected, I have no problems at all. On everyone's computers, the drives are mapped liked `\\ServerName`.
Also when I say `\\10.0.0.75` when connected to the VPN and I type in a username and password it works just fine.

The server with the shared files is a running Microsoft Server 2008 R2, and the OpenVPN server is on Ubuntu 18.04.

Why can I not use `\\ServerName` to connect to the shared drives when going through the VPN?

I do have access to the OpenVPN server if I need to change anything. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Client config file**

```
client
proto udp
remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 1194
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
verify-x509-name server_S0sFBDyPTuNCNvKX name
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
cipher AES-128-GCM
tls-client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
setenv opt block-outside-dns # Prevent Windows 10 DNS leak
verb 3
<ca>

</ca>
<cert>

</cert>
<key>

</key>
<tls-crypt>

</tls-crypt>
```

**OpenVPN server.conf**

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option WINS 10.0.0.75"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key 0
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_S0sFBDyPTuNCNvKX.crt
key server_S0sFBDyPTuNCNvKX.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

Comment: Is it possible that `\\ServerName` is not known by your home computer?

Comment: It should be, I have a laptop that travels with me and `\\ServerName\share` has already been mapped.

Comment: Did you notice the line `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.75"` and that when you say "Also when I say \\10.0.0.75 when connected to the VPN and I type in a username and password it works just fine."... ? maybe it is an hint.

Comment: yes, that was me trying to see if that would help. It did not do anything. I did change that line to be `push "dhcp-option WINS 10.0.0.75"` and when I connected it work, but when I disconnected, and then try to reconnect. It no longer works and I get an error saying 'Microsoft Windows Network: The network path was not found"

Comment: Laxer it is difficult to understand from remote. You changed DNS into WINS in the file `server.conf`. Period. Then you restart the server (as e.g. `sudo service ...`)? Reboot machine? Reboot the drive? Only try to connect to the shared drive? Try to connect with an already established connection? With a new one? How you tried, with `\\ServerName`, with `10.0.0.75` ? When it worked when not? What said the configuration file when it worked? When not? `:-)` For you it is easy to understand what happened, you were there... for the readers less...